# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets issues

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebview

I'm using `Qt 5.7.1` and I have problem with undefined `QtWebView`. I have found and download from the link - https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases

`qtwebkit_tp4_qt57_msvc2015_x86.zip` and copy the content of the archive to `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015`. Now it found `QtWebView` but the problem is with the object:

**test.h**

```
QtWebView *mapBrowserView;
```

**Errors:**

```
error: C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

[image: 0_1504343524118_2017-09-02_121132.png]

So it doesn't work. I think installation should be different. How to fix it? Thanks in advance for the help.

It seems I have circular include `QtWebView` but I included it only once. It's strange.

Comment: `QtWebView` or `QWebView`, is typo?

Comment: Did you enable webkit in your .pro file? https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_WebKit

Comment: @eyllanesc

Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: @drescherjm

Yes, I have included in .pro - `QT += widgets core gui network webview webkitwidgets concurrent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is how I have fixed it:

1. Copy the contents of the archive `qtwebkit_tp4_qt57_msvc2015_x86.zip` to `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015`;
2. Include `webkitwidgets` to `.pro` file;
3. Include `#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>`
4. Initialized the `QWebView *mapBrowserView;` object;

Now it's all compile and work.